# Changes in synchronized replica not shown in ArcMap or ArcCatalog without refreshing

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I am  synchronizing a one-way replica in ArcEditor using Python. I tried adding RefreshActiveView and RefreshCatalog to the code, but I still need to refresh the synchronized database to see the results. Here is a code snippet:

```
Connection_to_geoDBReplicationTest = "C:\Connection to geoDBReplicationTest.sde"

Connection_to_geoDBRepTest_2 = "C:\Connection to geoDBRepTest_2.sde"

arcpy.SynchronizeChanges_management(Connection_to_geoDBReplicationTest_sde,
 "GISUSER.timedTestReplica2", Connection_to_geoDBRepTest_2, "FROM_GEODATABASE1_TO_2",
 "IN_FAVOR_OF_GDB1", "BY_OBJECT", "DO_NOT_RECONCILE")

arcpy.RefreshCatalog(Connection_to_geoDBRepTest_2)

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Any thoughts? the code does work, but I would prefer the user did not need to refresh the database in ArcCatalog each time...

Comment: Is the child connected to the Default version on geoDBRepTest?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help in your case, but you might want to add a garbage collect prior to running both refreshes.   This has worked for me in the past where an empty results database wouldn't allow itself to be deleted by a script.

```
import arcpy, gc

synchronize changes

gc.collect()
refresh catalog
refresh active view
```